# Add trigger to AWS Lambda Function using Java API

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

How can I add new trigger for existing AWS Lambda function using Java API?

I would like to add `CloudWatch Events - Schedule` trigger.

It looks like I should use `AmazonCloudWatchEventsClient`.
How can I set the credentials for the client?

Any examples will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to add event sources via aws sdk. I faced the same issue and please see code below as the solution using java.

```
AddPermissionRequest addPermissionRequest = new AddPermissionRequest();
addPermissionRequest.setStatementId("12345ff");  //any unique string would go
addPermissionRequest.withSourceArn(ruleArn); //CloudWatch rule's arn
addPermissionRequest.setAction("lambda:InvokeFunction");
addPermissionRequest.setPrincipal("events.amazonaws.com");
addPermissionRequest.setFunctionName("name of your lambda function");

AWSLambdaAsyncClient lambdaClient = new AWSLambdaAsyncClient();
lambdaClient.withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1); //region of your lambda's location

lambdaClient.addPermission(addPermissionRequest);
```

Comment: This works fine for me, but only problem is `AWSLambdaAsyncClient` is deprecated.

Comment: @chaitanya it works also with `AWSLambda` client

`AWSLambda lambdaClient = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks needed it in Kotlin myself, the thing missing from the previous answer was the dependency:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:1.11.520'
```

code:

```
val addPermissionRequest = AddPermissionRequest()
addPermissionRequest.statementId = "12345ff"  //any unique string would go
addPermissionRequest.withSourceArn(ruleArn) //CloudWatch rule's arn
addPermissionRequest.action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
addPermissionRequest.principal = "events.amazonaws.com"
addPermissionRequest.functionName = "name of your lambda function"

val lambdaClient = AWSLambdaAsyncClient.builder().build()
lambdaClient.addPermission(addPermissionRequest)
```